# What is the exterior algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I am learning differential geometry, and I have difficulty understanding the construction of the **exterior algebra** of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$.

We have the wedge product
$$\wedge:\Lambda^k(V^\ast)\times\Lambda^l(V^\ast)\to\Lambda^{k+l}(V^\ast)$$
defined as
$$\omega\wedge\eta=\frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}\operatorname{Alt}(\omega\otimes\eta)$$
and that's all right. Then one just define the exterior algebra to be the direct sum
$$\Lambda(V^\ast)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\Lambda^k(V^\ast),$$
and that is supposed to be an algebra. But $\wedge$ is defined only on $\Lambda^k(V^\ast)\times\Lambda^l(V^\ast)$, so how does it act on a general element? Component wise?

> **Question:** If $(\omega_0,\ldots,\omega_n)\in\Lambda(V^*)$ and $(\eta_0,\ldots,\eta_n)\in\Lambda(V^*)$, what is $$(\omega_0,\ldots,\omega_n)\wedge(\eta_0,\ldots,\eta_n)?$$

Comment: What do you mean that $(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n) \in \Lambda (V^*)$? If you mean to write these as members of the direct sum, with $\omega_i \in \Lambda^i(V^*)$, then that wedge product would just be $\sum_{i,j} \omega_i \wedge \eta_j$, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does exterior algebra actually mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729411/what-does-exterior-algebra-actually-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of $\omega_i$ and $\eta_j$ are elements of a particular $\Lambda^k$.  It is perhaps more enlightening to write
$$
\omega_0+\omega_1+\cdots +\omega_n.
$$
Do the similar thing for the $\eta_j$.  Then, you multiply using the distributive property and the fact that you know the wedge product for each pairing of $\omega_i$ with $\eta_j$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So it make sense to write, for example, $3+dx-5dx\wedge dy$? My book was not so clear about this...

Comment: @user224761 It does make sense to write that.

Answer (score 0):

- The equation
  $$\Lambda=\bigoplus_{m=0}^n\Lambda^m$$
  means that $\Lambda^m\subset\Lambda$ and the function
  \begin{align}
  \Lambda^0\times\cdots\times \Lambda^n&\to\Lambda\\
  (\omega_0,\ldots,\omega_n)&\mapsto \omega_0+\ldots+\omega_n
  \end{align}
  is bijective, not necessarely that $\Lambda=\Lambda^0\times\cdots\times \Lambda^n$.
- If $\omega=\omega_0+\ldots+\omega_n\in\Lambda$ and $\eta=\eta_0+\ldots+\eta_n\in\Lambda$, then
  $$\omega\wedge\eta=\sum_{i=0}^n\omega_i\wedge\sum_{j=0}^n\eta_j=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\omega_i\wedge\eta_j$$
  since the wedge product is bilinear. In addition, you can use the fact that $\omega_i\wedge\eta_j=0$ if $n<i+j$:
  $$\omega\wedge\eta=\sum_{i+j\leq n}\omega_i\wedge\eta_j$$